# Sequelize ORM: How to connect to MYSQL on localhost, using the 'host' property?

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp, sequelize.js

I'm trying to connect to my local MYSQL(ran by XAMPP) through Sequelize:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.MYSQL_DB, 'root', '', {
  host: process.env.CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  logging: false
});
```

The process.env.CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL variable is set to "localhost", just like the documentation says(i'm using this specific variable because i want to deploy to Heroku later)

I'm getting the following error:

> getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost'; localhost';:3306

The process.env.MYSQL_DB variable is just the name of my database.

It all worked when i was using the "short way" to connect:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.MYSQL_DB , "root", "", {
   dialect:'mysql',
   logging: false
});
```

Can someone tell me what might be wrong with my setup?

EDIT: if anybody is interested, the problem was that i put a semicolon after the variable deceleration in my .env file.......

Comment: Check the quotes of the environment variable CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL. You can see it by typing `console.log(process.env)`.

Comment: Yeah the problem was a semicolon...I'm new to node, so wasn't aware you aint supposed to add one..